# Jekyll - How to pull frontmatter variables from other pages

Tags: html, jekyll

Ok, so what I want to accomplish is to have, on my main page, my latest comic, it's title and description. All my comics are in *"/comics/#"*. The title and description of the comics is in the front matter, and added to the page via the layout. I have the most recent comic number saved in the _config.yml file, and so I'm able to pull the image from the comic simply by saying *"/comics/{{ site.latestComic }}/comic.jpg"*. However, I can't do the same thing with the title and description as those are embedded in the index file.

So, what I need to know is how to access page variables in other files. Or perhaps a good work around.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out myself. I don't know if this is the best answer, but it works.

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
    {% if p.comicNum == site.newestComic %}
        {{ p.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Goes through every page and checks for comicNum (a variable in each of my comics) and if it's equal to newestComic (a variable in my _config.yml), it will grab the title out of it. My intuition tells me a function that iterates over the entire site for a single value is bad, but this isn't a large site and this is only done during deployment so it likely won't be an issue.

Comment: I think your solution is good. The only way to do it and not iterate over all the pages is to generate some JavaScript variable and then check it client-side in page load. But I'd still do it at generation time as you have.